# Hibernate ignore a column if not exists in the table

Tags: hibernate

How to ignore a column in the table if it is not exists in hibernate, but column name variable is there in the entity?

Comment: Use **@Transient** on the variable.

Comment: what you want??

Comment: @AngadBansode, i have a table that is not having a column, but in my entity i have mapping that column, so how can ignore this column from read and assign default value. i hope this is cleared.

Comment: you are using hibernate orm tool right??,how ur table is created?.

Comment: Yes i am using hibernate, table is created with manual script.